# Directional Derivative of distance function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

For the function, $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, do directional derivatives exist at the origin? If I use the definition $$lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+hv)-f(x)}{h},$$ then I get $$\frac{|h|}{h}$$ which is without limit. But in some places, I keep reading that the directional derivative is 1.

Also, if I were to write the function in spherical coordinates, it would be simply $f(\rho\theta)=\rho$, which is differentiable in $\rho$, irrespective of $\theta$.

What is the source of this ambiguity and is there a convention for this?

Comment: However, a one-sided directional derivative exists everywhere, that is, $df(x,h) = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} {f(x+th)-f(x) \over t}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that the directional derivatives do not exist at the origin, as you correctly proved; the right (well... or left depending on $v$) directional derivative is 1.

The second function you defined using spherical coordinates (I'm assuming you forgot $\phi$) is the same function as $f(a, b, c) = a$, which is obviously different from the first one.

Comment: How is it a different function? It is the same function, now in spherical coordinates? Why should derivatives depend on choice of coordinate system?

Comment: The first function (the names you use for the variables do not matter, this is important to understand) maps $(a, b, c)$  to $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. The second one maps $(a, b, c)$ to $a$; also they have different domains. How can they be equal?

Comment: My contention is that finally the numbers should match up whatever coordinate system I use. I want to know what ambiguity is there in the polar coordinate system at origin.

Comment: @Vivek let's simplify and work in $\mathbb R^2$ using polar coordinates. Your function then maps $(a, b)$ to $a$ and is defined for $(a, b) \in [0, \infty] \times [0, 2\pi)$. Do you think this function is differentiable at $(0, 0)$?

Comment: Ok I agree with you, they are not the same. But in this link, they describe finding directional derivative in a given direction using polar coordinates. Is this procedure correct?                   http://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/chapter06/section04.html

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate $f(\rho, \phi, \theta) = \rho$ at $0$ with respect to $\rho$ without a problem. But if you want to differentiate with respect to $x_i$ you obviously run into trouble, since $\rho = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2 ^2 + x_3^2}$.

Comment: Finding the derivative in the direction $e_1$ should be the same as fixing the angle at 0 and then differentiating with respect to $\rho$, or am I wrong?